# Emit inline assembly from byte array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have these arguments in a C++ function:

```
unsigned char originalBytes[], int originalBytesLength
```

And this loop to emit the bytes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < originalBytesLength; i++)
    __asm _emit originalBytes[i];
```

I get an error saying `"Improper operand type (C2415)"` from the last line, however. Is there a way to emit the bytes without hardcoding them?

What I'm trying to do is to pass a byte array to the function and have it emit the bytes with inline assembly. As such the bytes may differ on each call.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Execute compiled bytes residing in a buffer?

Comment: as others have noted, _asm and _emit are not runtime constructs.  They are used only during compilation to write opcodes/bytes into the compiled binary.  There is no such thing as "emitting bytes" at runtime.  Again, are you trying to have the CPU execute the bytes in the array at runtime?  Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Do you want to execute the bytes? It may be possible depending on your environment to execute the bytes at runtime but it involves tricks which are not recommended.

Comment: If you just want to execute the bytes in a quick and really dirty way, call `((void(*)(void))&originalBytes)()` and make sure there's a return at the end of the buffer (0xC3 for x86 CPUs) : http://ideone.com/fN12u1 But please don't.

Comment: @tux3 that solution assumes the memory containing originalBytes is executable.

Comment: @superultranova it usually is if you mark your buffer const, due to R^X, but yes you're right. This is by all metrics ever an awful solution, except that it fits in two lines and sometimes mostly work :)

Comment: @tux3 you're right about the const buffers, and the awful solution.  I died a little inside when I wrote my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably doesn't do what you think it does.

First, you can't use __asm _emit in a loop, it's not "aware" of the code surrounding it.
It's like trying to use an #include in a loop if you want, it's only going to be processed once.

And most importantly _asm _emit is not something you can use at runtime, or with a variable, not even a constexpr.
It's just a way to dump a raw byte literal in your application at compile time, once.
So there really isn't a clean way to do what you're trying to do with __asm _emit. You'd have to emit that buffer byte by byte at compile-time or use a more convenient inline ASM block.
So no, there's no way to emit the bytes without hardcoding them.

Be also aware that the compiler doesn't try to understand what the bytes you just dumped in the middle of the binary mean. If you're modifying registers, or writing position-dependant code, this will likely conflict with what the compiler is doing and cause awful bugs.

EDIT:

> What I'm trying to do is to pass a byte array to the function and have it emit the bytes with inline assembly. As such the bytes may differ on each call.

You can't do that with __asm _emit. 
There's actually no easy way to do exactly that at runtime, because each time you emit a byte, you have to grow the binary. And that's **really** hard once the binary was already compiled.

It's *possible* if you have relocation infos and you're ready to suspend all threads, fix all of the relocations, rewrite the short jumps that don't fit anymore as long jumps (and re-fix the relocations, and refix the jmps, in a loop). Then fix the sections, relocate the other threads if necessary and resume. I've heard of malware doing (a simplified version of) that, but that's about it.

That said, you'll probably want to take a look at various JIT libraries. I know LLVM and GGC have one. 
You won't get exactly the same result, but a JIT is probably what you want.
You'll get a byte array that you can jump to with a function pointer, not code emitted at an arbitrary location at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to execute the bytes, and they are not known until runtime, you can write them to an read/execute region of memory, and then call the base of that region.  Be really sure this is what you want to do, and be very sure of the source of those bytes.  Outside of very specific circumstances, I don't reccommend doing this.  Here is how you would do it in windows.

```
typedef __cdecl void (* voidf_t)(); // make sure the calling convention is correct
void execute(LPBYTE bytes, DWORD len_bytes) {
    // bytes on the stack are NX on most modern operating systems, get some executable memory
    LPBYTE exec_region = (LPBYTE) VirtualAlloc(NULL, len_bytes, MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if(exec_region != NULL) {
        memcpy(exec_region, bytes, len_bytes);
        voidf_t fun = exec_region;
        fun(); // this will call the bytes
        VirtualFree(exec_region, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        fun = exec_region = NULL;
    }
}
```

There are many many considerations to be taken into account when using a technique like this.  You MUST know where the bytes you are executing came from.  The bytes you are executing must also be a function that returns, and is expecting to be called with the convention used in the typedef.  The code must also be completely position independent, since there is no relocation fixup being performed.  More often than not, code like this ends up being the source of vulnerabilities and/or instability in applications, so I urge you to consider if there are better solutions to your problem.